# Linq query how to select all columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `linq` query which is giving me desired output :

```
 var data = (from c in dtskip.AsEnumerable()
                        select new[]  { 
                         c.Field<string>("Suburb"), c.Field<string>("Postcode"), c.Field<string>("State"),c.Field<string>("ID"), c.Field<string>("SEARCHKEY"), c.Field<string>("RATING"), c.Field<string>("DELIVERY")
                       });
```

How can i select all the column instead of giving name like `c.field<string>("postcode")` .My output is the data only from datatable `dtskip` :

output:

```
["DARWIN","0800","NT","2","DARWINNT","A","Delivery Area"]
,["ALAWA","0810","NT","5","ALAWANT","A","Delivery Area"],
["BRINKIN","0810","NT","6","BRINKINNT","A","Delivery Area"],
```

is there any other way i can get the output in dis way from datatable using `linq` query .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataRow` contains an [`ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) member which returns all the data in that row as an array, the downside is they are all returned as `object`s but if all your columns are the same type you can cast the `ItemArray` in line to the desired type (in this case `string`)

```
dtskip.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.ItemArray.Cast<string>());
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` to work with.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
var data = (From c in dtskip
            select c).AsEnumerable(); //Not sure about the AsEnumerable :s
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var data = dtskip.AsEnumerable().
            Select(x => new 
                   { 
                              Suburb = x.Field<string>("Suburb"),
                              Postcode= x.Field<string>("Postcode"),
                              State= x.Field<string>("State"),
                              Id= x.Field<string>("ID"),
                              Searchkey = x.Field<string>("SEARCHKEY"),
                              Rating = x.Field<string>("RATING"),
                              Delivery = x.Field<string>("DELIVERY")
                   });
```